# Hugo Theme with "featuredpath"

Tags: hugo, static-site

I'm experimenting with hugo and [this theme](https://github.com/jpescador/hugo-future-imperfect). From the example site in the repo i can see, that posts featured images are configured the following way:

```
featured = "pic.jpg"
featuredalt = "Pic 2"
featuredpath = "date"
```

which requires me to place `pic.jpg` in `static/img/YEAR/MONTH`.
Can someone explain me, how this path gets assembled from `featuredpath = "date"`? Are there any other options? maybe relative the the source.md file? The templating magic happens [here](https://github.com/jpescador/hugo-future-imperfect/blob/master/layouts/post/featured.html), but there is nothing with `date` included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You noticed that `layouts/post/featured.html` is involved. But notice this line:

```
{{ partial "img-path" . }}
```

This means there's partial named `img-path` that gets inserted here. So we'll jump over to it. If you look in `/layouts/partials/img-path.html` you'll see this comment on line 7:

```
 if path is date then it will format the directory to year/date i.e. 2006/01
```

Then you see lines 18-24, which create the date-centric image path:

```
{{ $.Scratch.Set "path" "/img/" }}
{{ if eq $structType "shortcode" }}
  {{ $.Scratch.Add "path" (.Page.Date.Format "2006/01") }}
{{ else }}
  {{ $.Scratch.Add "path" (.Date.Format "2006/01") }}
{{ end }}
```

On a somewhat related note, I've found the [Hugo forums](https://discourse.gohugo.io/) valuable for getting quick feedback on questions like these.

Other great resources include blogs (like the one by [Régis Philibert](https://regisphilibert.com/tags/hugo/) and an [entry by the Future Imperfect theme's creator](https://jpescador.com/blog/future-imperfect-theme-release-on-the-go-hugo-static-website-engine/)) and the [Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/documentation/).